# Regular Expression (regex) fails even though the express matches the provided string and best/efficient way

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to implement custom regular expressions in my Java program to verify if my input string matches the regex. But for some reason, the regex fails at a particular point even though the input string matches it.

```
String input = "abc:def:id:identifier:123456.890123.1";
System.out.println(input.matches("(abc:def:id:identifier:).[0-9]{6,12}.[0-9]{1,6}.[0-9]{1,20}"));
```

The regex returns `false` at the point `123456` even though the input matches the length of 6.
If I give `1234567` then it would return `true`. I am wondering why it fails for `123456` even though it matches the length. Also, it does not fail for the next one where I have just `1` and length of `{1,20}`.

Also, is there a better way to verify this string in regex or this is a good and efficient way?

Comment: Your use of the dot (any character other than newline) is messing things up. You want to escape it using `\.`. Also I don't see a dot in your input after the colon, so you probably want to ditch that one.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked:
`input.matches("(abc:def:id:identifier:)[0-9]{6,12}\\.[0-9]{1,6}\\.[0-9]{1,20}")`. Also, one more doubt is this the only way to verify or there is a better way to verify the pattern in my input using regex? Any other better technique to validate the same.

Comment: @JvdV Please add this as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @JvdV, should remove `.` at the start which is causing the problem during the validation.

Following should work:

```
input.matches("(abc:def:id:identifier:)[0-9]{6,12}\\.[0-9]{1,6}\\.[0-9]{1,20}")
```